# add new field under groups in system > configration programmatically

Tags: layout, magento-1, payment-methods, system.xml

I want to add custom field in each payment method section programmatically. So when I am navigate to System > configuration > Sales > Payment Methods so can access that custom field in each payment method section.
here is example:

```
<sections>
      <payment>
            <groups>
                 <ccsave>
                    <myfield>   ...

                  <checkmo>
                        <myfield>   ...     
                 <ccsave>
                    <myfield>   ...

                  <authorizenet>
                        <myfield>   ...
```

I have tried this code but not get success:

**Event:**

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
                <observers>
                    <custom_controller_action_layout_load_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Dotsquares_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomNode</method>
                    </custom_controller_action_layout_load_before>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
        </events>
</adminhtml>
```

**Observer function :**

```
public function addCustomNode(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $current = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('section');
        if($current == 'payment'){

           $allAvailablePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();  

           $xmldict = new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base(Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')->getNode()->asNiceXml());

          if(count($allAvailablePaymentMethods) > 0){
            $nodeNew =  new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element('<specificshippingmethod translate="label">
                                    <label>Applicable Shipping Methods</label>
                                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                                    <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                </specificshippingmethod>');

              foreach($allAvailablePaymentMethods as $paymentKey => $PaymentVal){
                $xmldict->getNode('sections/payment/groups/purchaseorder/fields')->appendChild($nodeNew);

                /*foreach ($xmldict->getNode('sections/payment/groups/'.$paymentKey.'/fields')->children() as $nodeName => $node) {
                    echo "$nodeName => "; echo '<pre>';print_r($node); echo '</pre><br>';
                 }*/
             }
           }
          //$config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')->getNode()->asNiceXml();
            //header("Content-Type: text/xml");
            //echo $config; die;

        }

     }
```

Please help me how can I do this. 
I want to do this only by programmatically, because in future may be more payment methods will be added.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml    Check this file and create node or edit these file